# How to open a .wmz extension file?

Tags: windows-media-player

I got a .wmz file from my boss. It seems to be a Window Media Player file, but I don't know how to open this file. Or maybe it is something else. Please help.

Comment: What does your boss want you to do with the file? Certainly you could ask him that, could you?

Comment: He is not here anymore. Will not meet him for couple of hours more. But when he come I have to show him this file. He doesnot even know what is this. he also got from his boss.

Comment: @diwasbhattarai This maybe of assistance http://skindoc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

To identify type of a file from its content (regardless its name) you can use the [`file` utility](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/).

- Either download a standalone binary of an older version of the utility: [File for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)
- Or perform a minimal installation of [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) and select also `file` during the installation.

Usage:

```
file the_file_to_check.wmz
```

Answer (score 1):

WMZ files are Settings Files primarily associated with Windows Compressed Metafile (Microsoft Corporation).

According to this [Click Here](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-wmz/)  you should try to determine what type of file it is by double clicking on it.  Windows will then try to determine if there is a program installed to open this file.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the file's extension from `.wmz` to `.zip`. If you can then open it in an archive program like 7-Zip then it's most likely a Windows Media Player skin.

Otherwise, it's probably an image file. XnView should be able to open it.